# Draw shadow on image while drawing on DrawingContext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I draw an image in OnRender method of my custom FrameworkElement. I would like to draw a shadow of this image as well. I need to do this in code, and I would not like to use DropShadowBitmapEffect because it is obsolete. How can I achieve this?

```
    public class MyDrawingView : FrameworkElement
    {
        protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
        {
             drawImagesOnDrawingContext(dc);
        }

        public RenderTargetBitmap getBitmap()
        {
            DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext dcMine = dv.RenderOpen())
            {
                drawImagesOnDrawingContext(dcMine);
                dcMine.Close();
            }
            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(200, 200, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            rtb.Render(dv);
            return rtb;
        }

        private void drawImagesOnDrawingContext(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
        {
            //how to draw shadow on bi?
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\mytemp\img1.jpg"));
            dc.DrawImage(bi, new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100));

            //how to draw shadow on bi1
            BitmapImage bi1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\mytemp\img2.jpg"));
            dc.DrawImage(bi1, new Rect(30, 30, 100, 100));
        }

    }
```

Note that the solution suggested by SvenG below, to add an effect to the underlying element, doesn't work for me because it gives a shadow to the whole element, not the individual images I draw. For example, if I were to have two overlapping DrawImage, the suggested solution will draw shadow considering the whole. The shadow of upper image will not be drawn on the lower image.

Additionally, I want to create a bitmap using the getBitmap function as shown above to export the drawn image with the shadows.

Comment: Are the bitmaps transparent? ie Do you want to shadow individual pixels of the bitmap, or just a rectangular shadow for each bitmap?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Bitmaps can be transparent so a rectangular shadow for each bitmap will not work. But, right now I can't figure out how to draw a rectangular shadow either!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an old `PushEffect()` call on `DrawingContext` that would have done what you required, but like BitmapEffect this is obsolete.

`BitmapEffect`'s replacement is the `Effect` class. There is a subclass called `DropShadowEffect` that is exactly what you are after, but unfortunately as SvenG says, this cannot be applied directly to bitmaps.

The lowest level element that supports applying effects is the `DrawingVisual` class. This isn't too bad because `DrawingVisual` is a pretty lightweight class. There is no layout overhead. Your best bet would be to create each bitmap in its own `DrawingVisual`, and set the `Effect` property of the visual to a `DropShadowEffect`. Obviously if you have thousands of bitmaps it may not be a viable solution.

All this can be done in code, although not `OnRender()` since each visual has its own render context. However, for child DrawingVisuals to render properly, you need to tell the framework about them.

You need to override two methods in your custom element in order to see these visuals: `VisualChildrenCount` to say how many children you have, and GetVisualChild() to return them to the system. Because of this you will need to keep a collection of visuals available. You can also call `AddVisualChild()` and `AddLogicalChild()` if you want to do hit testing against them.

```
public class MyDrawingView : FrameworkElement
{
    List<DrawingVisual> _visuals = new List<DrawingVisual>();

    public MyDrawingView()
    {
        CreateVisuals();
    }

    //Gets a bitmap rendering of the visual and its children for saving as image file
    public RenderTargetBitmap GetBitmap()
    {
        var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(200, 200, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        rtb.Render(this);
        return rtb;
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _visuals.Count;
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return _visuals[index];
    }

    private void CreateVisuals()
    {
        CreateVisualForBitmap(@"D:\mytemp\img1.jpg", new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100));
        CreateVisualForBitmap(@"D:\mytemp\img2.jpg", new Rect(30, 30, 100, 100));
    }

    private void CreateVisualForBitmap(string bitmapPath, Rect bounds)
    {
        var bitmap    = new BitmapImage(new Uri(bitmapPath));
        var visual    = new DrawingVisual();
        visual.Effect = new DropShadowEffect();

        using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            dc.DrawImage(bitmap, bounds);
        }

        _visuals.Add(visual);
        AddVisualChild(visual);
        AddLogicalChild(visual);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you suggest I create a bitmap out of this drawing that I can save as an image file? I do this using getBitmap function shown in my original code.

Comment: Have added a GetBitmap() function above.

Comment: This does work! One issue I have is that even though my app will not have thousands of bitmaps but it can have hundreds of bitmaps created out of user photos. I can use re-sized bitmaps to conserve memory while the user draws on screen, but while exporting final image I would like to use the full bitmaps; so memory might be a problem as it seems all of the bitmaps will be loaded together. Is there a way that bitmaps can be loaded sequentially?

Comment: WPF rendering does not work like that. OnRender() effectively gives instructions on HOW to render, but actual rendering can be done at any time behind the scenes by the framework. Due to this, if you want full size bitmaps, WPF will still store them all even if you supply them sequentially. You could perhaps use smaller versions until you want to export, but at that point you will still need to load all the full size bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your OnRenderMethod:

```
  ....

  dc.DrawImage(bi, new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100));

  // Create DropShadow
  DropShadowEffect effect = new DropShadowEffect();
  effect = new DropShadowEffect();
  effect.Color = Colors.Gray;
  effect.Direction = 45;
  this.Effect = effect;
```

Comment: This solution solves my problem partially. The problem I have with this is that if I were to have two overlapping  DrawImage, this solution will draw shadow considering the whole. The shadow of upper image will not be drawn on the lower image.

Comment: Hi SvenG, can you also suggest how I can resolve the issue described in the comment above.

Comment: Amaltas, the problem is that effects can only be applied to UIElements, which is what I have done here: Your DrawingView has one Effect, regardless on how many Images you draw with your drawingContext. 
From my perspective it feels somehow wrong to have a FrameworkElement and draw multiple BitmapImages on it. 
Why not create a UserControl or a Style that contains your DrawingView Elements and additionally Image Controls with the images you want to display?