# Trying to add rows to bottom of gif image in byte array using C# and then add to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, arrays, gif

I am trying to add a drop shadow programmatically to each image that I am processing in C#.  The images come to me in the form of byte[] and are gif images.  I am basically trying to "append" 10 rows to the bottom of each image to create a drop shadow effect and then add them to a pdf using itextsharp, but no matter what I do the images display fine but the extra rows do not appear.  I have tried looking at the header information in the image and am able to identify the width and height of the image, however I have not been able to identify the termination string in the header so that I can reverse engineer the format that I need to use to add the extra rows.  I have also tried doing the addition to the image in itextSharp, but I could not get that to work either.  I am open to doing it either way.   Here is what I have so far:

```
//create bytearray with enough room to copy original image + 10 rows   
//of gradient.  Img[8] = height of image  Img[6] = width of image
byte[] totalImg = new byte[Img[8] + ((int) Img[6] * 10)];
//Increase height of image in gif header 
Img[8] = (byte) (Img[8] + 10);
//Copy original image w/increased height to new byte array
Img.CopyTo(totalImg, 0);

int writeIdx = Img.Length;

//create 10 gradient rows and add them to the total image
for (int x = 9; x >= 0; x--)
{
    //create new row the width of original image
    byte[] gradient = new byte[(int) Img[6]];

    //make first 6 bytes white
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 6; idx++ )
        gradient[idx] = 0;

    //make rest of that row all one color, darker to lighter rows
    for (int idx = 6; idx < (int) Img[6]; idx++)
    {
        gradient[idx] = (byte)((x + 10) * 10);
    }

    //copy gradient to total image
    gradient.CopyTo(totalImg, writeIdx);
    writeIdx += gradient.Length;
}

iTextSharp.text.Image writeImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(totalImg);
writeImg.ScaleAbsolute(72, 92);
PdfPCell imgcell = new PdfPCell(writeImg);

imgTbl.AddCell(imgcell);
```

Based on Bruno's comments I have now tried this, which also does not work.  The images display but there are not additional rows at the bottom of the image.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
int extraRows = 10;
byte[] totalImg = new byte[Img.Length + ((int) Img[6] * extraRows * 3 * 8)];

Img[8] = (byte)(Img[8] + extraRows);
Img.CopyTo(totalImg, 0);
int writeIdx = Img.Length;

//create 10 gradient rows and add them to the total image
for (int x = extraRows - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    byte[] gradient = new byte[(int)Img[6] * 3 * 8];

    //make first 6 pixels white
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 144; idx++ )
        gradient[idx] = 0;

    //make rest of that row all one color
    for (int idx = 144; idx < (int)Img[6] * 3 * 8; idx++)
    {
        gradient[idx] = (byte)((x + 10) * 10);
    }
    //copy gradient to total image
    gradient.CopyTo(totalImg, writeIdx);
    writeIdx += gradient.Length;
}

iTextSharp.text.Image writeImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(totalImg);
writeImg.ScaleAbsolute(72, 92);
PdfPCell imgcell = new PdfPCell(writeImg);

imgTbl.AddCell(imgcell);
```

So, this is what I have tried using the RawData from the image in iTextSharp.  It has the same results in that the image displays fine, but no additional rows appear at the bottom of the image.

```
int extraRows = 10;
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(td.ImageData);
byte[] totalImg = new byte[img.RawData.Length + ((int)img.Width * extraRows * 3 * 8)];
//copy raw image data into the total image
td.ImageData.CopyTo(totalImg, 0);
int writeIdx = img.RawData.Length;

//create 10 gradient rows and add them to the total image
for (int x = extraRows - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    byte[] gradient = new byte[(int)img.Width * 3 * 8];

    //make first 6 pixels white
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 144; idx++)
        gradient[idx] = 0;

    //make rest of that row all one color
    for (int idx = 144; idx < (int)img.Width * 3 * 8; idx++)
    {
        gradient[idx] = (byte)((x + 10) * 10);
    }
    //copy gradient to total image
    gradient.CopyTo(totalImg, writeIdx);
    writeIdx += gradient.Length;
    }

    iTextSharp.text.Image writeImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(totalImg);
    writeImg.ScaleAbsolute(72, 92);
    PdfPCell imgcell = new PdfPCell(writeImg);

    imgTbl.AddCell(imgcell);
```

Ok, so in the third option above this line     td.ImageData.CopyTo(totalImg, 0); should be     img.RawData.CopyTo(totalImg, 0);  But when I make this change it throws an error:  "The byte array is not a recognized imageformat."

The option below actuallys works to a certain extent.  The image does display and the extra rows display at the bottom of the image.  However, the image is grayscale instead of color.  The reason I used 1 for the colorspace is because that is what was listed as the value for the colorspace in the iTextSharp.text.image img when I debugged and the 8 was what was listed as the value for the bpc in the variable img.

```
int extraRows = 10;
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(td.ImageData);
byte[] totalImg = new byte[img.RawData.Length + ((int)img.Width * extraRows * 1 * 8)];
//copy raw image data into the total image
img.RawData.CopyTo(totalImg, 0);
int writeIdx = img.RawData.Length;

//create 10 gradient rows and add them to the total image
for (int x = extraRows - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    byte[] gradient = new byte[(int)img.Width * 1 * 8];

    //make first 6 pixels white
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 48; idx++)
        gradient[idx] = 0;

    //make rest of that row all one color
    for (int idx = 48; idx < (int)img.Width * 1 * 8; idx++)
    {
        gradient[idx] = (byte)((x + 10) * 10);
    }
    //copy gradient to total image
    gradient.CopyTo(totalImg, writeIdx);
    writeIdx += gradient.Length;
    }

    iTextSharp.text.Image writeImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance((int) img.Width, (int) img.Height + extraRows, 1, 8, totalImg);
    writeImg.ScaleAbsolute(72, 92);
    PdfPCell imgcell = new PdfPCell(writeImg);

    imgTbl.AddCell(imgcell);
```

Since the option above made my images display as grayscale, I decided to try making my colorspace 3 and bpc 8 as in the following option, but this threw the error "Insufficient data for an image".

```
int extraRows = 10;
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(td.ImageData);
byte[] totalImg = new byte[img.RawData.Length + ((int)img.Width * extraRows * 3 * 8)];
//copy raw image data into the total image
img.RawData.CopyTo(totalImg, 0);
int writeIdx = img.RawData.Length;

//create 10 gradient rows and add them to the total image
for (int x = extraRows - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    byte[] gradient = new byte[(int)img.Width * 3 * 8];

    //make first 6 pixels white
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 144; idx++)
        gradient[idx] = 0;

    //make rest of that row all one color
    for (int idx = 144; idx < (int)img.Width * 3 * 8; idx++)
    {
        gradient[idx] = (byte)((x + 10) * 10);
    }
    //copy gradient to total image
    gradient.CopyTo(totalImg, writeIdx);
    writeIdx += gradient.Length;
    }

    iTextSharp.text.Image writeImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance((int) img.Width, (int) img.Height + extraRows, 3, 8, totalImg);
    writeImg.ScaleAbsolute(72, 92);
    PdfPCell imgcell = new PdfPCell(writeImg);

    imgTbl.AddCell(imgcell);
```

Comment: If `h` is the height of your image and `w` is the width, then the `byte[]` for the image has `w * h * c * bpc` bytes where c is the number of colors (1 for black&white, 3 for RGB and 4 for CMYK) and bpc is the number of bits per component. For instance, if you have an RGB image where the color value of each pixel is described using 1 byte, then the `byte[]` should have `w * h * 3 * 8` bytes. I have never seen an image where the `byte[]` has `h + (w * 10)` bytes as seems to be the case in your code. This line doesn't make any sense: `byte[] totalImg = new byte[Img[8] + ((int) Img[6] * 10)];`

Comment: Well, maybe my remark is completely wrong, but I am really confused: what type of image is `Img`?

Comment: You're not even close... What is the nature of your images? Right now you act as if they are raw images, but the fact that iTextSharp can process them without knowing the width, height, bpc and color space contradicts this.

Comment: The images are gifs. Please look at the edits above as I have tried multiple options.  I believe the last two are closer, but I am still missing something.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  @Bruno

Comment: Just to be clear, you are being given images that you are _then_ adding to a PDF using iTextSharp, right? You aren't extracting images from an existing PDF and are trying to manipulate them, right?

Comment: Your images are GIF images, yet you ignore that when you manipulate the bytes. You then use a lot of dark magic based on wrong assumptions. It is very unlikely that this will work. Instead you should use something like `System.Drawing.Image` to manipulate your image. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895371/draw-shadow-on-image-while-drawing-on-drawingcontext

Comment: Unless we hear back from the OP today I'm going to remove the iTextSharp tag from this post since this question, as far as I can tell, is really about modifying a GIF at the byte level. The fact that they are putting the image into a PDF afterwards should have zero effect on the image itself.